# Is there a SQL function that can populate missing dates in Date column and fill the same record in column B with previous value? (PostgresSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

The link article explains and answers my requirement in R. How do I achieve this in PostgreSQL? 
https://blog.exploratory.io/populating-missing-dates-with-complete-and-fill-functions-in-r-and-exploratory-79f2a321e6b5

In summary:

[image: Image of Initial table]

Basically in the table shown, I want to auto create new records of missing dates (range from 10-02 to 10-14).

[image: Table with date created]

The problem of this table is, the data of **discount rate** and **product** is still missing. The SQL statement should be able to detect, when there is first item in range (for example in **discount rate** column), the subsequent empty records in the **discount rate** will be populated with the same value of first item until there is another item found, then repeat the process.

For example, **discount rate** from **10-02** to **10-14** should be 0.1 (based on previous value on 10-01) and from **10-16** onward should be 0.2 (based on previous value on 10-15). How do I achieve this in SQL if it involves hundreds and thousands of records?

Comment: Hi there, sorry this is my first post. I am using postgres and pgadmin as query tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can left join to a list of dates generated through `generate_series()`

```
select ...
from generate_series(date '2020-10-01', date '2020-10-14', interval '1 day) as g(dt)
  left join your_table t on t."date" = g.dt::date
where ...
```